# How to use different versions of Node simultaneously using NVM

Tags: node.js, nvm

Steps we have tried :-

1) We installed nvm and its node version in our CI server.

2) There are two projects. Both use different versions of node.

3) When we run 'nvm use version' . Same node version is set for both the projects. Due to this simultaneous build is not working.

Is it possible to use different versions of node simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

Works for Linux. You can see I have two versions of node is installed in my machine

```
   ->     v10.15.3
          v12.10.0
```

Then I ran

```
`nvm alias default node`.
```

In the current cli my node version is 10.15.3.

Now open another cli window and check that. For me that is is 12.10.0.

So set a default version then change around it using

```
nvm use your_desired_version
```

. See below image.

[image]

Comment: It's a continuous integration server . So builds will happen simultaneously.  So thinking if multiple versions can be activated at same time ..

Comment: I have updated my answer If you are Linux this will help